# Create File Location using API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, soap-api, ftp

I want to create a File location inside Salesforce Marketing Cloud using API. I am not able to find any API to create File location.

Does SFMC provide an API to create a File location using SOAP or REST API?

[image]

Comment: Not possible currently via documented or undocumented endpoints. Maybe something internal but nothing we could access.

Answer (score 0):

SFMC recently released REST based endpoints to manage filetransfer location - please refer - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/fileTransferReadFileTransferLocations.html?q=filetransferlocation

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce SE! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.